# How to prove that $f’(z) = e^{\alpha z^{2} + \beta z + \gamma}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f(z)$ is an analytic function of $z$ such that $f^{\prime}(z) \ne 0$ and $$\nabla^{2} \log|f^{\prime}(z)| = 0$$
where $$\nabla^{2} = 4\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}$$
If $|f^{\prime}(z)|$ is the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$, how do **I show** that $$f^{\prime}(z) = e^{\alpha z^{2} + \beta z + \gamma}$$
where $\alpha$ is real, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are complex constants.

Please any hint on how to approach this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$? The real and imaginary parts of $z$, respectively?

Comment: Yes, they are the real and imaginary parts of $z$

Comment: I don't see why $f'(z)$ should be that. $f(z)=z$ is a valid solution.

Comment: @Crypton If $f(z)=z$ then $f'=1=e^{0z^2+0z+0}$

Comment: the way to do it is as follows; $|f'(z)|=g(x)h(y)$ means $\log |f'(z)|=\log g(x)+\log h(y)=u(x)+v(y)$; but now $\log |f'(z)|$ harmonic so $u''(x)+v''(y)=0$ so $u''(x)$ is constant and so is $v''(y)=-u''(x)$ hence $u=ax^2+bx+c,v=-ay^2+dy+f$ so $|f'(z)|=g(x)h(y)=e^{a(x^2-y^2)+bx+dy+c+f},a,b,c,d,f \in \mathbb R$ etc

Comment: How do I get $\alpha z^2 + \beta z + \gamma$?

Comment: I mean how can get $f^{\prime}(z)$ now that we have $|f^{\prime}(z)|$. @Conrad

Comment: find a conjugate harmonic to $\log |f'(z)|=a(x^2-y^2)+bx+dy+c+f$ so for example $\Im \log f'=2axy+by-dx$ giving you $\log f'=\log |f'(z)|+i\Im \log f'=az^2+(b+id)z+c+f$ so $f'=e^{az^2+(b+id)z+c+f}$; the name for the constant $f$ is not really well chosen (not to confuse with the function of course), so maybe use constant $d_1$ or so instead

Comment: Thank very much. That works

Comment: @Conrad It looks like these comments should just be an answer